# Is HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash() thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, hash

I wasn't able to get a definitive answer on this so this question. There are few SO posts in the past that mentioned that instances of `HashAlgorithm` are not thread-safe quoting snippet in the MSDN doc.

See

- [Why does SHA1.ComputeHash fail under high load with many threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592596/why-does-sha1-computehash-fail-under-high-load-with-many-threads)
- [HMACSHA1.ComputeHash() thread-safety question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569683/hmacsha1-computehash-thread-safety-question)
- [Which piece of code is more performant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888204/which-piece-of-code-is-more-performant)

But, the [current MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm?view=net-6.0) doesn't say so. Surprisingly, the below code doesn't bomb on net3.1, net5.0, but *does* on net6.0. So, it looks like it was made thread-safe (perhaps), but perhaps net6.0 has a bug.

```
//<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net5.0;netcoreapp3.1;net48</TargetFrameworks>
[Explicit]
[Test]
public void Bork_HashAlgorithm()
{
    const int iterations = 1_000_000;
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("the overtinkerer");
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        Parallel.For(0, iterations, (i, loop) =>
        {
            md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
        });
    }
}
```

Exception message:

> SafeHandle cannot be null. (Parameter 'pHandle')

Comment: It's generally assumed in MSDN that an instance method is not thread-safe unless explicitly stated.

Comment: The problem with thread safety problems is that the buggy code can work just often enough to lull you into a false sense of security.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I can tell you first-hand that your statement is true. I've seen `HMACSHA256` `HashAlgorithm` shared instance work in PRD for years without issue on net3.1, but doesn't pass the above test. :exploding-head:

Comment: FFT: `net5.0`+ adds a thread-safe static method for md5 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5.hashdata?view=net-5.0). Similar for hmac (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.hashdata?view=net-6.0). Similar effort is also done for random with a static thread-safe impl (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-6.0). I went with the thread-safe static method as new'ing up was quite slower. `ThreadLocal<T>`/`ThreadStatic` are _faster_, and also an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe.

We're seeing same exceptions under peak load: `SafeHandle cannot be null. (Parameter 'pHandle')` and similar errors for MD5 provider, for SHA1, and for SHA256, all over the place.

**However we found that it's still beneficial to use a "singleton" instance of `HashAlgorithm` with a `lock`, it's still 3X faster than creating a separate instance every time.**

Here's the benchmark

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Gen2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MD5Recreate | 1,282.5 ns | 726.26 ns | 39.81 ns | 0.0801 | 0.0286 | 0.0038 | 512 B |
| MD5SingletonWithLock | 402.2 ns | 39.38 ns | 2.16 ns | 0.0610 | - | - | 384 B |
| MD5_HashData | 467.7 ns | 33.26 ns | 1.82 ns | 0.0548 | - | - | 344 B |

Here's the code:

```
static MD5 _md5 = MD5.Create(); // <-- one instance for all threads
public static byte[] MD5Hash(byte[] input)
{
    lock (_md5) // <-- use a lock
    {
        return _md5.ComputeHash(input);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: `MD5_HashData` is the new static `MD5.HashData` method introduced in .NET 5 - it's not faster than using `lock`. However `MD5.HashData` shows better performance under heavy parallelism, which BDN cannot emulate (see comments below)

UPDATE2: adding benchmarks for SHA256

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHARecreate | 2.211 us | 3.7097 us | 0.2033 us | 0.1144 | 0.0534 | 736 B |
| SHASingletonWithLock | 1.231 us | 0.1349 us | 0.0074 us | 0.0954 | - | 608 B |
| SHA_HashData | 1.296 us | 0.0737 us | 0.0040 us | 0.0877 | - | 552 B |

Comment: I see similar results in benchmark.net. But with `Parallel.For()`, `MD5_HashData` is 4x faster than `MD5SingletonWithLock`. So, I'm not convinced with the benchmark.net results. (See https://github.com/rmandvikar/random2/compare/dev...hashalgorithm)

Comment: @hIpPy fair poin! However, your test code runs a million operation in parallel which is far from our real load (I assume `Parallel` is internally limited by the number of CPU cores?) However, thanks for the data. I guess one should peak the preferred method based on their scenarios.

Comment: @hIpPy I have just updated the answer with SH256 benchmarks as well

Comment: I see. With `maxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`, I get similar results to benchmark.net, but with `maxDegreeOfParallelism = 2`, `SHA_HashData` is still ~1.6x faster than `MD5SingletonWithLock`. :shrug: I don't feel that's far-fetched.

Comment: That said, my question doesn't specifically ask for a _faster_ or _fastest_ option, just a _correct_ option. So I'm willing to accept your answer. I'd request that you please add a caveat to the point about perf I made (else the answer would look misleading). FWIW, I went with thread-safe static method (`SHA_HashData`).

Comment: Am I blind? Where is the implementation for the referenced methods? E.g. `SHA_HashData`

Comment: @Jaans it's the built-in `SHA.HashData`